# How to round to half, always in positive direction?

Tags: c#, vb.net, function, math

How do I achieve the below rounding?

0.012608376 > 0.015

2.1  > 2.5

2.4 > 2.5

2.5 > 2.5

2.6 > 3

.01 > .05

Comment: The first and last requirements seem very different to the title and the other requirements. Is `.01 > .05` what you meant? If so, more explanation is required. You also do not specify what should happen to negative numbers.

Comment: If .01 -> .05 and 0.012608376 -> 0.015, then how would you, in words, describe the round algorithm?

Comment: Your example data makes no sense.  In what world does 1.01 round up to 1.05?

Comment: -1 for non-sensical question.

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? Do we have to question someones coding problem, or should we just help solving it? I don't understand all these negative votes. If it is not clear enough, just ask and it will be clarified. No need to down-vote.

Comment: I don't understand why this gets closed. Why isn't it a real question? Could anybody explain this?

Comment: @Stefan : the requirements are such that it is not possible to represent algorithmically. "Round to half" and ".01 > .05"/"0.012608376 > 0.015" are contradictory requirements. Having given the OP ample opportunity to update their question, no further info has been provided. This makes the question impossible to answer, hence closure is appropriate.

Comment: @spender: I provided a working solution. Let's call it "rounding to a half decimal place". You just need another argument which says to *which* decimal place. IMO, that's not very unusual. We have such rounding algorithms in our system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public double Round(double input, int decimalPlaces)
{
  double precision = 2.0 * Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces - 1);

  // Ceiling also rounds negative values in positive direction
  return Math.Ceiling(x * precision) / precision;
}
```

Use like this:

```
Round(0.012608376, 3) returns 0.015
Round(2.1, 1) returns 2.5
Round(2.4, 1) returns 2.5
Round(2.5, 1) returns 2.5
Round(2.6, 1) returns 3
Round(.01, 2) returns .05
```

Better to be used with decimals, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the response Stefan. I was not able to reply earlier to the valid queries by all. I should have added in my OP that our application and database supports a max of 3 decimal places as per requirement. That is why input of 0.012608376 was to return 0.015 though for .01,  .05 would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

```
static double RoundHalfUp(double value) {
            var scale = 1.0;
            while (value * scale < 0.1) scale *= 10;
            return Math.Ceiling(value * 2) / (2 * scale);
        }
```

Sample code. This doesnt take into account special cases at all, and yes, it fails your first case as it isn't clear what you want. Refine the question please.

Comment: First and last case output 0.05, so no :-)

Answer (score 0):

Take the decimal place that you want to round at. If that greater than 5 round up. If less than 5 round down and add 5 (to that decimal place), if equal to 5 do nothing.

2.1 > round down to 2.0 > add .5 > 2.5

2.4 > round down to 2.0 > add .5 > 2.5

2.5 > 2.5

2.6 > round up 3

This is difficult because you are never rounding on the same decimal place. Is there not a better way to do this? You shouldn't be rounding data to a different place depending on how many decimal points it is. For instance, you should always round to tenths, or always round to hundredths, not round there dependent on the data.