# Round 100.11 to 100.15 and 100.16 to 100.20 in c#

Tags: c#

Round 100.11 to 100.15 and 100.16 to 100.20 in c#

I have tried all these things but none of these helps me.

```
Math.Round(100.11, 2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); //gives 100.11

Math.Round(100.11, 2,MidpointRounding.ToEven);//gives 100.11

Math.Round((Decimal)100.11, 2)//gives 100.11

(100.11).ToString("N2"); //gives "100.11"

Math.Floor(100.11);// gives 100.0

(100.11).ToString("#.##");//gives "100.11"

Math.Truncate(100.11);// gives  100.0

Math.Ceiling(100.11);//gives 101.0

(100.11).ToString("F4");// gives "100.1100"
```

Comment: Did you try `Math.Round(100.11,0)`?

Comment: 100.11 to 100.15?? Do you mean to 100.10?

Comment: @ Aishvarya
Math.Round(100.11,0);
100.0

Comment: Stumbled across this while having the same issue...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189463/how-to-round-to-half-always-in-positive-direction

Comment: I need to round up if value is 100.11,100.12,100.13,100.14,100.15 then the output will be 100.15

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question *needs samples badly*; if **round up** with delta equals to **1/20** is expected, i.e.:

```
  100.10 -> 100.10
  100.11 -> 100.15 // <- round UP; that's why 100.15 not 100.10
  ...
  100.15 -> 100.15
  100.16 -> 100.20
  ...
  100.20 -> 100.20
  100.21 -> 100.25
```

you may use this simple code

```
  Double value = 100.11;
  Double result = Math.Round(value * 20.0 + 0.49999999) / 20.0;
```

Answer (score 8):

This should give the desired result

```
decimal Round (decimal value, decimal granularity)
{
  return Math.Ceiling(value/granularity+0.5M)*granularity;
}

//  myResult = Round(110.11,0.05);
//  myResult = Round(110.16,0.05);
```

In general: Set the granularity to the decimal value of how you want the values to be rounded, e.g. `0.1` will round up to the nearest decimal. You may also apply odd values like `0.25` which will round to `0.25`, `0.50`, `0.75` and `1.0`.

Removing the `+0.5M` will simply round to the nearest value (instead of rounding up).

Comment: I face this error while trying your solution Round(110.11,0.05);
The best overloaded method match for 'webapp1.test.Round(decimal, decimal)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: You have to call it like: ``Round(110.11M, 0.05M)``, so the compiler will know it has to call the method with ``decimal`` parameter.

Comment: var s1 =Round(110.11M, 0.05M) //give 110.15 but var s2 = Round(110.16M, 0.05M);// this give 110.2

Comment: @user1416420: The question did not state what is expected for the values you tested. If you want the results you mention, remove the +0.5M.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Alzaimar is very interesting and useful. But note that it is NOT entirely useful when dealing with float or double values.

In general, you can use a similar approach to cleanly "Granularize" floating point values:

```
public double Granularize(double value, double granularity)
{
    var precision = (Decimal.GetBits((decimal)value)[3] >> 16) & 0x000000FF;
    return Math.Round(Math.Round(value / granularity, 0) * granularity, precision);
}
```

*Obviously, you can derive ceiling methods for float/double using the same basic premise.*

I just wanted to point out that using a granularity such as 0.1d will NOT give a properly granularized result without rounding to the precision of the granularity. You will sometimes get a spurious imprecision somewhere out around the 13th decimal place.